# LIBRTMP Delphi: use dll

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, rtmp

I have before me the task of loading and saving rtmp stream from the server to your computer. Exploring the internet, I came to the conclusion that it is necessary to use the library **LIBRTMP**. I work in Delphi XE2 and the only appropriate code I found on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580891/librtmp-delphi-mapping-of-the-dll) and sales on [Pascal page](http://pastebin.com/29XeZMvk).
I am having difficulties with the translation of this code into a usable form for delphi, because types `cint`, `pcchar` and etc I did not recognize.
I do not work with C or C + +, could you give me directions to work, or it's easier to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map those types in Delphi using following code:

```
Type
cint = longint;
cchar = shortint;
pcchar = ^cchar;
```

And try to recompile your code.

Comment: uses
 ctypes,
 sockets; ctypes - not used in delphi?

Comment: function RTMP_HashSWF(url:pcchar; var size:cuint; hash:pcuchar; age:cint):cint;cdecl;external External_library name 'RTMP_HashSWF';   hash:pcuchar -  replacement in delphi?

Comment: Actually `TArray0to6OfPcchar` and `AVal` are fully defined in [Pascal Page](http://pastebin.com/29XeZMvk). And `cvar` is just a directive to tell Delphi that the variable value is taken from external library.

Comment: hash:pcuchar - replacement in delphi?

Comment: or better way is you can search the unit file `ctypes.pas` and `sockets.pas`. I believe `cint`, `cchar`, `pcchar` ... is defined in those units.

Comment: `pcuchar: ^cuchar;` and `cuchar: byte;`

Comment: RTMPProtocolStringsLower : TArray0to6OfPcchar; cvar; external;
cvar; - indicates an error when trying to compile: "[DCC Error] lrtmp.pas(313): E2029 ',' or ':' expected but ';' found"

function AMF_EncodeString(output:pcchar; outend:pcchar; var str:AVal):pcchar;cdecl;external External_library name 'AMF_EncodeString';
External_library - showing error when trying to compile: [DCC Error] lrtmp.pas(318): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'External_library'

Comment: @Anvar sorry I mixed up with FPC implementation of `cvar` and Delphi. For Delphi you can't load variable from external library.

Comment: Hi,
I managed to fix the error, but I did not get to use
var
  MY_RTMP: RTMP;
  URL_str: AnsiString;
begin
  URL_str: = 'rtmp :/ / localhost: 1935/Video/test.stream';
  MY_RTMP: = RTMP_Alloc;
  RTMP_Init (MY_RTMP);
  RTMP_SetupURL (MY_RTMP, pcchar (URL_str));
  RTMP_Connect (MY_RTMP, 0);
  RTMP_ConnectStream (MY_RTMP, 0);
end;

Error RTMP_Connect (MY_RTMP, 0); - [DCC Error] fMain.pas (36): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical
thanks in advance