# Record the stream by calling the library LIBRTMP Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, rtmp

```
var
  MY_RTMP: RTMP;
  URL_str: AnsiString;
begin
  URL_str: = 'rtmp :/ / localhost: 1935/Video/test.stream';
  MY_RTMP: = RTMP_Alloc;
  RTMP_Init (MY_RTMP);
  RTMP_SetupURL (MY_RTMP, pcchar (URL_str));
  RTMP_Connect (MY_RTMP, 0);
  RTMP_ConnectStream (MY_RTMP, 0);
end;
```

Error RTMP_Connect (MY_RTMP, 0); - [DCC Error] fMain.pas (36): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical
thanks in advance

Comment: The `RTMP_Connect` expects to have a declared `RTMPPacket` type variable passed as a second parameter.

Comment: Well, clearly you have a type mismatch. The procedure expects different parameters. Do you expect us to hunt around and work out what parameters are expected. Your code has the declaration for `RTMP_Connect`. You can see what parameters it expects. We can't. At the absolute minimum, show us `RTMP_Connect`.

Comment: I got it from [`the link`](http://pastebin.com/29XeZMvk) from OP's previous question. It expects the `RTMPPacket` type variable for second parameter.

Comment: @TLama The point is that we should not have to hunt around. You should make your comment an answer. It clearly is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RTMP_Connect` as it is defined in [the code](http://pastebin.com/29XeZMvk) you've linked in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12798181/960757) expects to pass a declared `RTMPPacket` variable as a second parameter. So using your naming convention, you may try this:

```
var
  URL_str: AnsiString;
  MY_RTMP: RTMP;
  MY_RTMPPacket: RTMPPacket;
begin
  URL_str := 'rtmp://localhost:1935/Video/test.stream';
  MY_RTMP := RTMP_Alloc;
  RTMP_Init (MY_RTMP);
  RTMP_SetupURL (MY_RTMP, pcchar (URL_str));
  RTMP_Connect (MY_RTMP, MY_RTMPPacket);
  RTMP_ConnectStream (MY_RTMP, 0);
end;
```

Perhaps `MY_RTMPPacket` needs to be initialised before `RTMP_Connect` is called. But no doubt you can work that our from the library's documentation.

Comment: Yes, it works, but I can not find the function record stream, could you give way to record the flow

`var
 MY_RTMP: RTMP;
 URL_str: string;
 MY_RTMPPacket: RTMPPacket;
 URL_char: PAnsiChar;
begin
 URL_str:='rtmp://localhost:1935/Video/test.stream';
 MY_RTMP := RTMP_Alloc;
 RTMP_Init(MY_RTMP);
 RTMP_SetupURL(MY_RTMP, pcchar(URL_str));
 RTMP_EnableWrite(MY_RTMP);
 RTMP_Connect(MY_RTMP, MY_RTMPPacket);
 RTMP_ConnectStream(MY_RTMP,0);
 RTMP_Read(); -?
end;`

thanks

Comment: @Anvar Read your question again. Nowhere do you ask us to help you learn how to use this library. In fact you don't even ask a question. You just give some code and a compiler error message. The only conclusion we can draw is that you need help solving the compiler error. This answer deals with that and you should simply accept the answer. Now, if you want to ask questions about how to use the library, please feel free to do so. But they would need new questions. And do make much more of an effort when asking the question. I know you are new here. I recommend the [faq].